# Включение openvpn из скрипта

Tags: openvpn

Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки, или функции, которые включают и выключают openvpn из скрипта, меня интересует только клиентская сторона.

Answer (score 1):

На bash, запускать от рута

Включение

```
openvpn --config /path/to/config.ovpn
```

Выключение

```
killall openvpn
```

Comment: а для python есть что-нибудь, или только subprocess?